# sqlite improving speed of query with JOIN over two (or more) tables

Tags: sqlite

Consider the following tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (aid, deleted DEFAULT 0, …other columns…);      -- ~300K rows
CREATE TABLE b (bid, deleted DEFAULT 0, aid, …other columns…); -- ~1.1M rows
CREATE INDEX ix_a_deleted_aid (deleted, aid) WHERE deleted = 0;
CREATE INDEX ix_b_deleted_bid (deleted, bid) WHERE deleted = 0;
```

I get the following query performance

```sql
SELECT Count(aid) FROM a WHERE deleted = 0; -- ~300ms
SELECT Count(bid) FROM b WHERE deleted = 0; -- ~80ms

SELECT Count(bid) 
FROM b JOIN a ON b.aid = a.aid 
WHERE b.deleted = 0 AND a.deleted = 0;      -- ~2700ms
```

How can I speed up that last query to the order of the first two?

Here are the query plans for the different queries

```sql
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT Count(bid) FROM b WHERE deleted = 0;
-- SEARCH TABLE b USING COVERING INDEX ix_b_deleted_bid (deleted=?)

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT Count(bid) FROM b JOIN a ON b.aid = a.aid WHERE b.deleted = 0 AND a.deleted = 0;
-- SEARCH TABLE b USING INDEX ix_b_deleted_bid (deleted=?)
-- SEARCH TABLE a USING COVERING INDEX ix_a_deleted_aid (deleted=? AND aid=?)
```

Comment: Run an [`ANALYZE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) and see if the query planner reorders the join given the extra stats that generates?

Comment: unfortunately no difference

Comment: Hmm. I *think* that since a has fewer rows moving it to the first table will help (Unless that's not the case when you look at just the `deleted=0` rows of the two tables). See https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#crossjoin for how to manually control the order, or try swapping the two tables in the current query. But if that doesn't work, you might be out of luck for shaving off some time. The join involves a lot more work than the simple counts and it'll never be as fast...